# Mongoose updateMany does nothing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to update all documents where `start` is lower or equals than the `start` of the new date (`savedDispo`) and `end` is greater or equals to the `start` of the new date. I want to update the `end` of all these documents with the start of the new date.

```
DispoSchema.statics.EditDisposInBetween = function(savedDispo){
    this.updateMany({
        start : { 
            $lte : savedDispo.start 
        }, 
        end : { 
            $gte : savedDispo.start 
        }, 
    },
    {$set:{end: savedDispo.start}});
}
```

Actually, it does nothing, but with the data I'm testing, it should update.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: IMO, the problem could be in the conditions (`start` & `end`). Because date field query is bit tricky.

Comment: Also, check the format of the date what's passed to query and that in DB

Answer (score 0):

`updateMany` is only a query. It's not executed.

I had to add `.then()` at the end.